# App using Retrofit 2 waits for one minute before exiting

Tags: java, retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp, threadpoolexecutor

I'm using [Retrofit 2](http://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/) to make asynchronous calls. The problem is that after the response is received (`onResponse` is done with its work), the application still waits for 60 seconds before quitting.

This is the essential bit:

```
Call<MyResponse> call = client.resource();
call.enqueue(new Callback<MyResponse>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<MyResponse> c, Response<MyResponse> response) {
        // This gets called in a few milliseconds
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<MydResponse> c, Throwable t) {
    }
});
```

It looks like some `ThreadPoolExecutor` is waiting to time out (maybe in okhttp). But shouldn't the pool become free after the response is received as there is nothing else to process?

Is this a bug, am I misusing it, or is it normal to wait for 60 seconds when there is in fact nothing else to process?

How do I make the application exit right after the `onResponse` is done?